# Application defined or Object defined error in excel vba

Tags: vba

I am new to excel. I need to create a new excel from the macro written and need to add some data and save it as a csv file. I am getting  Application defined or Object defined error. Her is the code

```
Sub splitIntoCsv()
Dim wbIn
Dim wbIn1 As Workbook
Dim header As Variant
Set wbIn = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
wbIn.Workbooks.Add
'wbIn.Worksheets(1).Name = "TestData"
'Set wbIn1 = Workbooks.Open(Sheet1.Range("b25").Value, True, False)
header = Split(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2").Value, ",")
For k = 1 To 10
DoEvents
Next k
For i = LBound(header) To UBound(header)
'MsgBox header(i)
**wbIn.Worksheets(1).Range("a" & i).Value = header(i)**
Next i
wbIn.Worksheets(1).SaveAs Filename:="D:\file.csv" & Filename, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

I got the error at the Starred lines.Help needed,
Thanks in advance,
Raghu.

Answer (score 1):

The following code now work, Please have a look

```
Sub splitIntoCsv()
Dim wbIn As Excel.Application
Dim wbIn1 As Workbook
Dim header As Variant

Set wbIn = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wbIn1 = wbIn.Workbooks.Add

header = Split(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2").Value, ",")
For k = 1 To 10
DoEvents
Next k
For i = LBound(header) To UBound(header)
'**wbIn1.Worksheets(1).Range("a" & i).Value = header(i)**
Next i

wbIn1.SaveAs Filename:="D:\file.csv" & Filename, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
wbIn1.Close
Set wbIn1 = Nothing
wbIn.Application.Quit
Set wbIn = Nothing
End Sub
```

The first problem in the code was that you were trying to save using the worksheets. Worksheets do not have a save method, Workbooks do.

While fixing the code, I had a large number of excel objects in memory. Please have a  look at how to close and exit a excel application.

Answer (score 1):

For the starred line you asked about, note that the `Split` function returns a zero-based array, so in your first time through the loop you are trying to refer to cell `A0`. So, change the line to:

```
wbIn.Worksheets(1).Range("a" & i+1).Value = header(i)
```